# With Lyx Math, is there an official symbol for "implies"?

Tags: math-mode, equations

Complete Lyx/Latex newb here.

Just wondering, as I write one equation and then on the next line the next, is there an official symbol for "implies" (or "therefore")? Could be an arrow ... or three dots...?

Comment: There does exist in latex  a `\implies` and a `\therefore` commands (in math mode).

Comment: Thanks. As I'm starting with Lyx, I wonder how I find out what `\implies` corresponds to? I assume it must be one of the available Math symbols ...

Comment: Probably (I don't know the details of Lyx, as I  typeset directly code). If needed, at least \therefore requires the `amssymb` package.

Comment: In math mode in LyX you can select that symbols (and many others) from a  bottom bar that appears automatically. Moreover, you can also just type "\implies" in math mode (blue box) and LyX will change the command by the symbol in the edit screen, without have to make a PDF preview.

Comment: Got it... "long right arrow"... Thanks